# Should the main App component be Pure or Stateless?

Tags: react-native, optimization

In React-Native, should we use **Pure Component** or **Stateless Function** for the main Component ?

Here is two ways of doing it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './reducers/AppReducers';
import AppRoutes from './routes/AppRoutes';

// Pure Component
class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppRoutes />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

// Stateless Function
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppRoutes />
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Just learn about the differences of each.

Comment: @emix I know the difference ; I wonder if there is a case where the main Component would re-render if I used Stateless function, and not re-render with a Pure Component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your component is simple, use `stateless`. For simple components it is not required to use `Pure Components`

Let's say if you have a component that displays a text and you make it a pure component, Everytime it re-renders it will first do the shallow comparison. 
In this situation a re-render would be performant then a shallow comparison.

It's upto you to decide weather your component would be performant if it checks for a shallow comparison or re-renders

TIP: If you have a very basic component, which only displays some basic stuff, use `stateless`.

https://medium.com/groww-engineering/stateless-component-vs-pure-component-d2af88a1200b
here it is explained in detail.

in your case, I would advice `Pure Component` as it contains your whole app, and a re-render would be more costly then a shallow comparison